# How long does plugin review usually take?

Tags: validation, review

WordPress [says](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/) that plugins are manually reviewed within a "vaguely defined amount of time". What's the experience? How long does this take, on average?

Comment: An answer shall be forthcoming in a vaguely defined amount of time.

Comment: Are plugins being manually reviewed now? I've always been under the impression it was pretty automated.. like I fill out the form and within a few days I get SVN info.

Comment: @helgatheviking I once got an e-mail with "what exactly are you doing with this line?", so yes. Otherwise, it shouldn't have to take a few days. Anyway, you can make your few days an answer if it's up to me. Please include how many data you have (so how many times you've experienced it this way).

Comment: Anywhere from 2 days to a week or so, they are not really reviewed line by line, I'm pretty sure they run a script that detect malware/urls/encoding/licenses, etc. At least it was like this a few years ago, more like casually and quickly browsed unless there are red flags.

Comment: @Wyck also that could be an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a few days to a week, as said in the comments. I can say I've experienced the same amount of time a few times now.

However, this is no *rule*.